# World of Warcraft servers

Tags: mmo, operating-system

Does anybody knows or have any info about the OS of the servers of World of Warcraft?

I have a "debate" with some friends about the OS behind WoW. They say it could be Win, which is very strange for me.

Comment: I don't know, but it *is* known, since unofficial servers exist.

Comment: The [Pirate Servers](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Blizzard-Wins-88-Million-Dollars-In-Pirate-Server-Lawsuit-152494.shtml) may be running Windows (or not), but that doesn't guarantee that Blizzard uses it. A pirate server just has to *emulate* the functions that WoW performs (combat resolution, etc), and over HTTP - it could be running on *AmigaDos* for all we know :) . And this is isn't really all that game *development* -related, is it - maybe move it to the game site?

Comment: Look at jobs that offer Blizzard (currently Activision Blizzard). For backed web developers one of the requirements *Comfortable with Linux/UNIX, bash, Apache.* Hence my guess that they keep all stuff on Linux servers.

Answer (score 1):

Most MMOs use Windows for servers mostly because of Visual Studio. VS is basically the only development and debugging environment that is worth its salt (cue *nix users saying that gdb is just as powerful as VS). This means that we all are generally developing both the clients and servers on Windows, so it is just easier to also deploy on Windows. There are some out there that will cross-compile the servers for production (clients are clearly always targeting Windows at the very least, even if you have a Mac version) but it ends up being a hard thing to maintain and it makes debugging production systems that much harder. The big exception is web-based games, those are almost always Linux based (and usually running Apache and/or Nginx).

Comment: Probably, but I will give you that example (offtopic) Dreamworks, Pixar and others use Maya on UNIX.

Comment: Those are not game companies, so I'm not sure I see the connection. Pixax and friends do not develop Maya itself, and something like Renderman is far far less complex than an MMO.